# Correlation bounds

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds

Is there any survey of results other than viola's on correlation bounds and its applications?
Also is there any lecture notes on gowers uniformity and its applications in proving correlation bounds?

Comment: I am not aware of any recent survey other than Viola's.
There is a good lecture on Gowers uniformity in (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Main/AdditiveCombinatoricsMinicourse) (and references therein). If you could elaborate a bit more on the specific need, maybe someone could point to a more specific location.